# blueprint container inside other container, set height: 100%

Tags: blueprint-css

Good Morning,
I'm working with blueprint css framework. My problem is that I can't set height: 100% of a container that is inside in an external container. (container is intended as container blueprint css class). I want that my internal container is height as external container.

class container is defined as:
.container { display: block; }

Set height: 100% doesn't work. but I can't change this property becouse it is part of blueprint css framework. 
Is there a workaround?
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Is your internal container set as `display:block` ? You can't set height on inline elements in the way you are describing.

I would inspect the html using Firebug and see what the computed style value for the display setting is for your internal container.

Comment: Yes. .clearfix, .container {
display: block;
} but it is part of blueprint css framework. Is there a workaround?